# java regular expression issue about capture group

Tags: java, regex

```
public void test(){
    String source = "hello<a>goodA</a>boys can <a href=\"www.baidu.com\">goodB</a>\"\n"
                + "                + \"this can help";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a[\\s+.*?>|>](.*?)</a>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
    while (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("laozhu:" + matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
laozhu:goodA
laozhu:href="www.baidu.com">goodB
```

Why the second match is not `laozhu:goodB`?

Comment: Because `[\\s+.*?>|>]` matches 1 symbol, a whitespace, `+`, `.`, `*`, `?`, `>` or `|`.

Comment: thanks,i fixed it by using <a(\s+.*?>|>)(.*?)</a>,and output group(2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
<a(?: .*?)?>(\w+)<\/a>
```

So your `Pattern` should look like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a(?: .*?)?>(\\w+)<\\/a>");
```

It matches `goodA` and `goodB`.

For the detailed description, look here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nY4fD9/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a.*?>(.*?)</a>");
```

Comment: <a.*?>(.*?)</a> can also match <abc>blabla</a>,so finally i used <a(\s+.*?>|>)(.*?)</a>